# javascript fraction to percent

Tags: math, percentage

When I tried to convert fraction in Javascript, I am facing a problem. 
I need to make a fraction value to percent value. 
                           a = 0.0175
It should be displayed as 1.75%.  I tried to multiply by 100. But I am getting some extra fractions added to  the right - 1.7500000000000002 . I just need 1.75, not any more zeroes added to the end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `toFixed()` to specify the number of decimal places.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
var a = 0.0175
var num = a * 100;
var n = num.toFixed(2)
```

Comment: Is it possible without specifying the length? sometime if the value is 0.03425, it should be shown as 3.425. I don't want to restrict the number of fraction position, or even fill it up with zero.

Comment: If you don't want the number of decimal place then directly multiple the two decimals but make sure to convert them in decimal which multiplying because JavaScript treat every thing a string

Answer (score 0):

multiply, round and divide:

```
// rounding to set precision or default precision = 3
function roundToPrecision ( value, precision ) {
  precision = ( typeof precision !== 'undefined' ) ? precision : 3;
  var mult = Math.pow( 10, precision );

  return Math.round( mult * value ) / mult;
}
```

usage:

```
var zzz = roundToPrecision( 123.1231232546 ); // 123.123

var aaa = roundToPrecision( 123.1231232546, 1 ); // 123.1
```

Comment: so much complexity for such a simple result

Comment: besides `toFixed()` returns string

Comment: ok. I tend to think that rounding should happen at the last moment, and for display purposes only, though. (in most cases)

Comment: that depends on precision you need to have for calculations. e.g. more than 3 digits after comma is more than excessive already if we talk about screen size(that what i used to work with)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function formatNum(n) {
    return Math.round(n * 1e4) / 1e2;
}

var a = 0.0175;
var n = formatNum(a); // 1.75

var b = 0.21;
var m = formatNum(b); // 21
```

It simply multiplies by 100*100, rounds the result and divides again by 100. The result is still a number and not a string as with the `toFixed`-approach.

Comment: Could you also add an explanation?